# Conformal Maps and Homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Is every conformal map from an open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ to an open subset $V$ a homeomorphism?  Here is why I think it is.  A conformal map is holomorphic (hence continuous and open) and bjiective.  Seems really easy but just want to make sure.

Comment: You might like to include the domain and range of your function. Do you want $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ or from subsets to subsets?

Comment: Yes, continuous, open, and bijective is all you need. If a map is open, its inverse (which exists here by bijectivity) is continuous. A continuous bijection with continuous inverse is by definition a homeomorphism.

Comment: @FlybyNight now fixed although it doesn't make a difference really.

Comment: @LeoSpencer Thank you. This is a better question as a result of your changes. Remember that the more detailed and accessible a question is, the more likely you are of getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For instance a conformal map is not always surjective or injective (take any non-trivial inclusion, and the regular exponential map as expamples which are not surjective and injective respectively). If a conformal map is injective and surjective to its codomain though, then it is a homeomorphism by the properties you state.

Comment: This is better suited to the comment section. The definition of a conformal map is pretty standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map

Comment: @FlybyNight given that there are two definitions on that page, one whose codomain is non-trivial ($f\colon U\rightarrow V$) and one where the codomain is equal to the whole complex plane $f\colon U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$), I do not agree with you. Given also that I gave examples of non-homeomorphic conformal maps (giving a counter example to the OP's claim), I again disagree. Given that I also gave necessary and sufficient conditions, fixing the OP's claim, I must once again disagree. Given that this answer fully answers the OP's question, I disagree.

Comment: I will agree though that my claim it depends on the definition is not true. I have removed this claim.

Comment: There is a single definition (in complex analysis): "*a conformal map is a function which preserves angles*". Perhaps you might like to list the "different" definitions.

Comment: @FlybyNight As I said, on the wikipedia page, one definition defines a conformal map $f\colon U\rightarrow V$ for $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, and the other defines a conformal map $f\colon U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ for $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ (since the OP edited their question, the first definition applies, with a suitable change from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$, and not the second). The definitions matter when considering the OP's question as $\mbox{Id} \colon U\rightarrow U$ is a conformal homeomorphism but $i\colon U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ given by inclusion is a non-homeomorphic conformal map.

Comment: They are not different definitions, they are different domains and ranges. The definition "*a conformal map is a function which preserves angles*" holds in both cases.